# How can I sync up a git repository with what I already have

Tags: git

So, I already have 98% of a git repository, but that's downloaded not cloned.

Can I tell git to only scan, download missing files and then work as if I cloned the repository, instead of having to download everything again?

Comment: Do you have just the files or the .git folder as well? What I'm asking is do you just have files or a repository?

Comment: can you detail what you did ?

Comment: @slebetman I have just the files.